# My images do not want to render in my flutter app. one of the images in my assets file renders but the others refuse to

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

[image]

The 'trucks' image renders in all the image widgets but none of the other pictures want to render in any of the image widgets.

Comment: restart you IDE and share pubspec.yaml  code

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had not added the other images to my pubspec.yaml code. I added them and the code acted as expected

Comment: Could you  help me on how to add text boxes and buttons on top of an image?

Comment: Yes @Thabo Thandekiso    Use stack

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70287885/how-to-display-text-with-png-in-the-stack/70288079#70288079